# Local (outside EC2) testing with Fog/Carrierwave and IAM instance profiles?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I understand that I can configure fog to use IAM instance profiles (I’m uploading to S3 via fog/carrierwave) by passing use_iam_profile => true. What I haven’t yet figured out is how to test my code outside of an EC2 instance, like on my local machine. Is there a strategy for this that people are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how others might be doing this, but this is the strategy I've come up with. I have a config.yml that looks like this:

```
default: &default
  aws:
    s3:
      bucket: 'my-production-bucket'
  fog: &fog
    credentials: &credentials
      provider: 'AWS'
      region: 'us-east-1'

development: &development
  <<: *default
  aws:
    s3:
      bucket: 'my-dev-bucket'
  fog:
    <<: *fog
    credentials:
      <<: *credentials
      aws_access_key_id: 'ID_WITH_DEV_BUCKET_ACCESS_ONLY'
      aws_secret_access_key: 'CORRESPONDING_SECRET'

test:
  <<: *development

production:
  <<: *default
  fog:
    <<: *fog
    credentials:
      <<: *credentials
      use_iam_profile: true
```

I'm also using this trick in app_config.rb to load my config.yml file (not required for this solution, but it'll make the next part make more sense to you):

```
require 'ostruct'
require 'yaml'

all_config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'config.yml')) || {}
env_config = all_config[Rails.env] || {}
AppConfig = OpenStruct.new(env_config)
```

Then, in my config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = AppConfig.fog['credentials'].symbolize_keys
  config.fog_directory  = AppConfig.aws['s3']['bucket']
end
```

Notes:

1. The `symbolize_keys` call there is necessary because by default I
   wind up with a hash with strings as keys, and Fog is looking for
   symbols.
2. Yes, I'm checking in an app ID and secret, but you don't
   have to; you could do this with environment variables instead.
   Personal choice here, and I may change it later.
3. This works as
   expected locally, but I haven't tried it in EC2 yet. Since in each
   Rails environment the `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.fog_credentials`
   hash comes out exactly as I expect it to, it should work just fine
   when I get there.

The end result is that in all environments, the `AppConfig.fog['credentials']` hash gets the same `:region` and `:provider`. In development, it also contains the ID and secret. In production it doesn't contain the ID or secret, but instead gets `:use_iam_profile => true`

Comment: I'm curious if this solution works with a different profile per user, and when you're dealing with temporary access tokens you'd get through the Cognito service. I'm about to find out otherwise ;-)